# Read property file of one java project in another java project

Tags: java, spring, maven

Here is my problem statement:

I have a project A which is built in spring and is a maven project. there is project B(not using any framework) which I am developing as a library whose responsibility is just to make some REST calls. I am calling functions in project B's classes from project A(Including B as a jar in A)

Now, while making some calls I realized I want to read the values in the local/UAT/PROD.properties file of project A in project B. The location of these files are A/src/main/resources/config.

How do I achieve this without passing the values as parameters from A to B?

Comment: I feel that this is a case of cyclic dependency. Project B is an external library to project A. And project B needs to read some properties from project A. So when you will deploy / bootstrap your application, which properties you will read first? IMO, you will need to pass on the properties to project B somehow. Or create a separate file which can be readable from project project A and project . This can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the property file that you want to use is actually included in `projectB.jar`. You might need to consult Maven documentation for that. If the file is in fact in the jar, then you could use -

```
Properties.load(getClass.getResourseAsStream("path/to/the/property/file.properties"));
```

to get hold of the props.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to move property file outside of package you compiled to make it independent from the environment you deploy.
You should also consider to add an environment variable (A_CONFIG_LOCATION) to point your property file to make it little bit more modular. To achieve this add this code segment to your servlet-context.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="file:${A_CONFIG_LOCATION}/configuration.properties" />

<beans:bean id="propertiesLoader"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

    <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="basenames">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>file:${A_CONFIG_LOCATION}/configuration
            </beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

By using this approach you will also be aware of any changes made to your property file at run-time in Spring app (App A). You can add same behaviour to App B by adding file change listener to your property file reader.

Answer (score 0):

answered the same query here, the implementation is pretty clean and simple as well. [How to read property values defined in a project from another project added as dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71983307/how-to-read-property-values-defined-in-a-project-from-another-project-added-as-d)

NOTE: avoid the reading the properties using absolute file path. Not good approach

register external bean as a component of your current project and then simply just use @Value