# How to read property values defined in a project from another project added as dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have few spring boot projects:

```
proj-A
proj-B
proj-C
```

Now I have developed another spring project:

```
proj-common-ABC
```

In `proj-common-ABC` I have externalised some common implementation of `proj-A proj-B proj-C` and using `proj-common-ABC` as maven dependency in `proj-A proj-B proj-C`

Now I want to read a property `all.service.common.property = value` defined in `proj-A proj-B proj-C` from `proj-common-ABC`.

How can i achieve this please help

Comment: Reads to me as if you could read such a Property by using `@Value` or `@ConfigurationProperties` as long as your component scan finds them or a `spring.factories` file loads a coresponding configuration. What have you tried?

Comment: @Matthias being honest the when i posted the question, i didn't tried any implementation. but i have got a hint from comment it helped me to resolve my issue. i will post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class in `proj-common-ABC` where we need to read the property

```
@Component
public class componentClass {
    @Value("${all.service.common.property}")
    private String property;
}
```

then we need to write a configuration class in our `proj-A proj-B proj-C`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.path.of.package"})
public class CommonABCComponentConfig {
}
```

This will read the classes marked with @Component annotation in the given packed and will load a bean into the application context. So there after using @Value annotation we can read the properties.